# How to write if condition with two statement in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am just confused about how to match two statement like `if else` of `JavaScript` in **React Native**

for e.g.,

```
if(array.length != null && array.length >= 2){
    alert("Array Is Greater Than 2")
}else if(array.length != null ){
    alert("Array Is Less Than 2")
}else{
    alert("Array is null")
}
```

I know how to pass signle condition in React Native like

for e.g.,

```
{
    array.length != null &&
    <View>
        /* Content Here */
    </View>
}
```

*or*

```
{
    array.length != null ?
    <View>
        /* If Content Here */
    </View>
    :
    <View>
        /* Else Content Here */
    </View>
}
```

But How do I create if state like first one ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have nested ternary condition check like

```
{
    array.length != null && array.length >= 2 ?
    <View>
        /* If Content Here */
    </View>
    :
    array.length != null?
     <View>
        /* Else if Content Here */
    </View>: 
    <View>
        /* Else Content Here */
    </View>
}
```

However you can simply do it using `if-else` in a function which you call from render as suggested by @MayankShukla since it is more readable then nested ternary operators

Answer (score 4):

You can have nested ternary conditions, but i will not suggest that because it will be not that readable. Other option is you can put all those conditions inside a function and call that function from render method.

Like this:

```
renderElement () {
    if(array.length != null && array.length >= 2){
        alert("Array Is Greater Than 2");
        return <p>If condition</p>;
    }else if(array.length != null ){
        alert("Array Is Less Than 2");
        return <p>If-Else condition</p>;
    }else{
        alert("Array is null");
        return <p>Else condition</p>;
    }
}

render () {
    const element = this.renderElement();
    // now you can use element to render that element at any place
}
```

Nested ternary conditions:

```
{
    array.length != null && array.length >= 2 ?
        <View>
            /* Array Is Greater Than 2 */
        </View>
    :
        array.length != null?
            <View>
                /* Array Is Less Than 2 */
            </View>
        :
            <View>
                /* Array Is Null */
            </View>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort as I found Nested ternary way more comfortable for me. Upvoting your answer for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Practically** I didn't find out a cleaner way for doing it in the way you want.

**Theoretically** you can do it with nested ternary operator, but it's pretty dirty and unreadable.

I always stick with creating a separate method, and invoke it in the render:

```
renderView() {
  if(array.length != null && array.length >= 2) {
    return <div>Array Is Greater Than 2</div>
  } else if(array.length != null ) {
    return <div>Array Is Less Than 2</div>
  } else {
    return </div>
  }
}

render() {
  return <div>{this.renderView()}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort as I found Nested ternary way more comfortable for me. Upvoting your answer for the help.