# how to write if else inside render return react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to write `if-else` inside `render return`. I want to write `if ImageSource === null` then I want to get the code below.

```
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    let source = { uri: response.uri };
    this.setState({
      ImageSource: source,
      data: response.data

    });
  }
});
```

here is inside render return

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        {this.state.ImageSource === null ? <Text>Select a Photo</Text> :
          <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />
        }
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

**else** I want to get the uploaded image.

Comment: What is the problem in this code ?

Comment: @Prasheel This code no problem, I want to implement if else inside the code.  ImageSource === null the the code above   else   else I want to get the uploaded image

Comment: I haven't see any issue in code.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh, thanks for your reply. the code can work but I want to implement if-else inside the code.

Comment: What is the default value for ImageSource?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I already update my code inside the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write if condition with two statement in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262287/how-to-write-if-condition-with-two-statement-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your condition **ImageSource** condition with **undefined**.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        {this.state.ImageSource === undefined || this.state.ImageSouce === null ? <Text>Select a Photo</Text> :
          <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />
        }
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: still have the bug on image missing

Comment: Can we talk vai skype or other middle? So I can help you to resolved the issue

Comment: That will help for both

Comment: Sent you a request. Kindly reply on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parenthesis and let me know if it did work.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
    <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        {this.state.ImageSource === null ? (
            <Text>Select a Photo</Text> 
        ):(
          <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />
        )}
     </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This code can work. I have the bug on image missing when backward still there. I try to put if else inside the code but cannot work.

Comment: @qing Do you think I should leave this answer or should I remove it?

Comment: this code no error can work but cannot solve my bug. No problem if you want to remove it. If you want to leave this answer no problem also. Anyway thanks for your reply and help me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong in your code?

or you can try this way.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
  <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>

    {!this.state.ImageSource && <Text>Select a Photo</Text> }
    {this.state.ImageSource && <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />
    }
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have the bug on image missing when backward still there.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you do inline conditional rendering like

```
{var && <MyComponent />}
```

which will render MyComponent if var is true. But it tried to render value of var. The fix is change conditions to make sure it's Boolean expression like

```
{var !== 0 && <MyComponent/ >}.
```

so you can change your code like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
  <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
    {this.state.ImageSource === null && <Text>Select a Photo</Text> }
    { this.state.ImageSource &&  <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />
    }
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

this should work! for more details refer to this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20084)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should split your render functions into several small function like:

```
renderTitle = () => <Text>Select a Photo</Text> 

renderImage = () => <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />

 render(){
  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        {this.state.ImageSource === null ? this.renderTitle() : this.renderImage()
        }
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
```